# Passing values of one file into another file as inputs

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

I have a file that contains following information in a tab separated manner:

```
abscdfr  2   5678
bgbhjgy  7   8756
ptxfgst  5   6783
```

lets call this file A and it contains 2000 lines

and I have another file B written in ruby

that takes these values as command line input:

```
f_id = ARGV[0]
lane = ARGV[1].to_i 
sample_id = ARGV[2].to_i
puts " #{f_id}_#{lane}_#{sample_id}.bw"
```

I execute the file B in ruby by providing the information in file A

./fileB.rb abscdfr  2   5678

I want to know how can I pass the values of file A as input to file B in a recursive manner.

If it was one value it was easy but I am confused with three values.

Kindly help me in writing a wrapper around these two file either in bash or ruby.

Thank you

Comment: Can't you split lines of input in the script?

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command will do the job in `bash`:

```
while read line; do ./fileB.rb $line; done < fileA
```

This reads each lines into `line`. Then it runs `./fileB.rb $line` for each line. `$line` gets replaced *before* the command line is evaluated, thus each word in every line is passed as its own argument, it is important that there is no quotation like `"$line"`. `read` reads from `STDIN` and would usually wait for user input, but with `< fileA` the content of `fileA` is redirected to `STDIN` so that `read` takes its input from there.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a little bash script to loop through each line in the file and output the contents as arguments to another script.

`while read line; do
  eval "./fileB.rb $line"
done < fileA`

This will evaluate the line in the quotes as if you typed it into the shall yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use one liner ruby :

```
ruby -ne 'system( "./fileB.rb  #{$_}" )' < fileA
```

Explanation :

- `-e`  Which allow us to specifies script from command-line
- `-n`  The other useful flags are `-n` (somewhat like `sed -n` or `awk`) , the flag tell ruby to read input or input file line by line like while loop.
- `$_`  Default ruby save current line stored in $_ variable